# Java Web Service on Jboss

Tags: java, eclipse, jakarta-ee, jboss

I am new to java web services and jboss. I have to make a connection between java and .net that's why I need to create a web service. The .net program is ready but the java portion is killing me. When I import 3rd party apis in java and  run the program as a java application there is no problem but when I run it as a web service it generates errors like:

```
C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\TestProjesiEAR.ear\TestProjesi.war\WEB-INF\lib\tcommon.jar\com\temenos\tocf\common\log\global.log (The system cannot find the path specified)

C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\TestProjesiEAR.ear\TestProjesi.war\WEB-INF\lib\tcommon.jar\com\temenos\tocf\common\conf\tcclientlog.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)

C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\TestProjesiEAR.ear\TestProjesi.war\WEB-INF\lib\tcommon.jar\com\temenos\tocf\common\log\global.log (The system cannot find the path specified)

C:\jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\deployments\TestProjesiEAR.ear\TestProjesi.war\WEB-INF\lib\tcommon.jar\com\temenos\tocf\common\conf\tcclientlog.properties (The system cannot find the path specified)
```

as i understand jboss cant find these files but these are already in the ../\TestProjesi.war\WEB-INF\lib folder.

Please can any one help me out...

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing them in your .ear/lib?  You might have to deploy the 3rd party jars as modules on the server.  More info and the process is [here](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/MODULES/Defining+a+module).
Basically you create a new directory in jboss_home/modules (using the 3rd party jar dirctory structure), add an .xml to the new module and register the new dependency in standalone.xml (for global dependency) or by creating a MANIFEST.MF in your .ear/META-INF.
[Master the Boss](http://www.mastertheboss.com/jboss-as-7/how-to-install-a-module-on-jboss-as-7) has some more info.
HTH